# How to remove rows of a dataframe based on values of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have a dataframe :

```
       col1  col2  col3
0      8     7     5
1      6     2     17
2      3     1     21
3      4     3     9
```

I want to remove every rows where col3 value is bigger than 10 and smaller than 20 and get the result :

```
       col1  col2  col3
0      8     7     5
1      3     1     21
2      4     3     9
```

How can i code this in python?

Answer (score -2):

Just extract everything that doesn't match the above criteria:

```
df[~((df.col3 > 10) & (df.col3 < 20))]
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     8     7     5
2     3     1    21
3     4     3     9
```